# My PC does not recognize Ubuntu, not even windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows

So i recently installed Ubuntu on my HP laptop which has windows 10 preinstalled, i quickly discovered that disabling legacy mode makes ubuntu impossible to boot, because it's not visible in boot menu. But when i have legacy mode enabled, I can select the "notebook harddrive" in efi boot menu and that boots ubuntu. There is no way to boot to grub or Windows os selection. So, how do i make my laptop boot into grub or windows os selection? (i mean that i want dualboot) I also checked a lot of posts but i couldn't fond one that would help me. i also tried to change default operating system to boot in windows, but there was only windows 10

Comment: You can't have one OS in legacy and the other in EFI mode.  If you can force the BIOS to only allow the mode that matches one of the OS', then you can reinstall the other in the same mode.

Comment: So is it possible to move ubuntu to uefi mode?

Comment: maybe you could reinstall it. "disabling legacy mode makes ubuntu impossible to boot, because it's not visible in boot menu" this problem maybe solved by changing your usb boot disk program. you may use rufus for making bootable disk.

Comment: I have flashed it with rufus but I cannot boot into it without legacy mode

Comment: Are you sure windows is still installed and wasn't overwritten when you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, because I even tried to boot into it, it boots first by default

Answer (score 1):

1. Plug Ubuntu flash drive and start pc  (i assumed that you used a flash drive to install Ubuntu)
2. Enter the boot options and select the usb drive right after pc has started.
3. Select "try ubuntu" when the ubuntu installation comes.
4. Follow the boot repair instructions
   [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair][1]

Comment: I wish it were that easy, it would have saved me hours of headaches.

Comment: But I need you be in uefi mode, but I cannot but to usb drive with uefi mode